# problem with c:when tag

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

Facelet:

```xml
<h:dataTable value="#{item1.zapas}" var="item2" >
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item2.hrac == null}"/>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="#{item2.hrac == null}">
                <h:outputText value="X"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="#{item2.hrac != null  }">
                <h:outputText value="#{item2.vysledok}"/>
            </c:when>

        </c:choose>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Output:

```
trueX
falseX

falseX
trueX
```

`item.hrac` is sometimes `null` and sometimes not `null` but in my choose it still choice  `null`. So what is wrong? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSTL tags and JSF tags doesn't run in sync as you'd expect from the coding. JSTL tags runs during JSF view build time only and the result is a tree of only JSF tags. JSF tags runs during view render time only and the result is a tree of only HTML elements.

When it's JSTL's turn to run during view build time, the `#{item2}` is not available in the scope simply because JSF hasn't run at that point.

To overcome this, you want to use JSF `rendered` attribute instead. Get rid of the whole `<c:choose>` block and put the following in place:

```xml
<h:outputText value="X" rendered="#{item2.hrac == null}" />
<h:outputText value="#{item2.vysledok}" rendered="#{item2.hrac != null}" />
```

#### See also:

- [<c:choose> not working in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580538/cchoose-not-working-in-datatable)
- [JSTL c:if doesn't work inside a JSF h:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442380/jstl-cif-inside-a-jsf-hdatatable)